# An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker Edit Row of DataGrid

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, entity-framework

i get this Error when would like to Edit some Row of my DataGrid...
[image]

Xml Code:

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ویرایش" >
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="TooltipEdit" MouseDown="Edit_OnMouseDown" Tag="{Binding Path=.}" Width="20" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Foreground="ForestGreen"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

i'm confused and tired to search dunno how to solve it..

```
 private void Edit_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        if (sender is PackIcon btnSender)
        {
            if (btnSender.Tag is Place place)
            {
                place.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
                _context.Entry(place).State = EntityState.Modified; // => Error here
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

if i remove or Comment relations `ICollection` and inheritance `BaseModel` Class from `Place` class this will be working as well
but i need them..

```
  public class Place:BaseModel// 
{
    [Key]
    public int PlaceId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long? PhoneNo { get; set; }
    public string Manager { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public short? RoomCounter { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Suite> Suites { get; set; } // 
    public virtual ICollection<Bed> Beds { get; set; } //
    public virtual ICollection<Device> Devices { get; set; } //
}
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var existingPlace=_context.Set<Place>().FirstOrDefault(i=> i.Id==place.Id);

if(existingPlace!=null)
{
 place.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
_context.Entry(existingPlace).CurrentValues.SetValues(place);
_context.SaveChanges();
}
```